# Third party cookies per site settings?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, session-cookies, payment-gateway, samesite

Have third party cookies blocked by default, and finally want to **allow** third party cookies for specific sites, well, because they don't work otherwise. Want to disable third party cookies for all sites **except** the ones I use for banking etc that are absolutely necessary for the site to function. Exceptions added to the "Whitelist" don't allow third party cookie functionality, either. No I'm not going to install an extension to make it work, either.
I know I have to add two attributes to the cookie which are **samesite = none**, **secure**. But this will cause our cookie to be sent to any site and ***is not secure*** at all.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are limited by the same origin which can take very specific values (strict, lax, none etc).

There is no way to access the cookie from another domain by setting this up.

There is a workaround by using the `CORS` headers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://server-a.domain.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
And you will
```

This will not work if you disable third party cookies from the browser.